# gtkmm4 building in Ubuntu 22.04 : Ninja : Unknown IO error

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, ninja, gtkmm4

```
raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-4.8.0$ meson setup --prefix /usr --libdir lib your_builddir .
The Meson build system
Version: 1.3.0
Source dir: /home/raphy/gtkmm-4.8.0
Build dir: /home/raphy/gtkmm-4.8.0/your_builddir
```

For size limits I've put the entire output of `meson setup --prefix /usr --libdir lib your_builddir .` command in google drive : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kvP_xitHnRaVyNmXLOy7ZBtjdP1zZyev/view?usp=drive_link

Execuing ninja got this error:

```
raphy@raohy:~/gtkmm-4.8.0/your_builddir$ ninja
[125/2744] Generating subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/manual/manual_html with a custom command
FAILED: subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/manual/html 
/usr/bin/python3 /home/raphy/gtkmm-4.8.0/subprojects/libsigcplusplus/tools/tutorial-custom-cmd.py html ../subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/manual/libsigc_manual.xml subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/manual/html
error : Unknown IO error
warning: failed to load external entity "http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/html/chunk.xsl"
cannot parse http://docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/current/html/chunk.xsl
[134/2744] Generating subprojects/libsigcplusplus/docs/docs/reference/html_and_tag with a custom command
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How to make it work?

Comment: Google Drive links are unacceptable to some of us because we do not want to give Google more information about ourselves.

Comment: I agree with you @tripleee . We should complain to StackOverflow for setting such low size limit for questions

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. There are plenty of Pastebin-like sites where we can view your data completely anonymously.

Comment: Which Pastebin-like sites do not have any size limits?

Comment: Of course, nothing is completely without size limits, not even Google Drive. If you expect us to need to review megabytes of data, something more fundamental is wrong with your question. Having said that, e.g. a Github gist should allow up to 100MB (haven't tested) and does not require us to have an account on the service to view it.